# GraphDatabaseService Shutdown() not returning

Tags: java, neo4j

We are using Neo4j2.0.1 on RHEL (jdk 1.7.. 51) - we invoke GraphDatabaseService.shutDown() on one synchronized thread, and this method never returns or throws any exception.

Other threads concurrently trying to access graph encounter this exception on `beginTran()`

```
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Database is currently not available. No blocking components
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:944)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TransactionBuilderImpl.begin(TransactionBuilderImpl.java:43)
        at net.ahm.graph.EmbeddedDBService.beginTx(EmbeddedDBService.java:275)
        at net.ahm.cm.graph.SummaryForPatientDAO.process(SummaryForPatientDAO.java:29)
        at net.ahm.cm.handlers.admin.GetSummaryPatientInfoMessageHandlerImpl.processAction(GetSummaryPatientInfoMessageHandlerImpl.java:15)
        at net.ahm.cm.handlers.common.BaseCareTeamHandler.doWork(BaseCareTeamHandler.java:46)
        at net.ahm.cm.handlers.common.CareTeamServicesHandler.processService(CareTeamServicesHandler.java:197)
        at net.ahm.cm.thrift.services.common.CareTeamServices$Processor$processService.getResult(CareTeamServices.java:178)
        at net.ahm.cm.thrift.services.common.CareTeamServices$Processor$processService.getResult(CareTeamServices.java:162)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TMultiplexedProcessor.process(TMultiplexedProcessor.java:123)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.AbstractNonblockingServer$FrameBuffer.invoke(AbstractNonblockingServer.java:516)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.Invocation.run(Invocation.java:18)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

What could be the possible reasons due to which the shutDown() method will block almost for ever.
Please advice.

Comment: Well the shutdown method simply shutdowns Neo4j so...the DB itself is not available...this is the reason why you have the Database is not available

Comment: the exception is obvious: shutdown called and same instance is used for beinTrans. However, what's weird is that control is not returning from shutDown()... not even throwing exception

Comment: can you provide a thread-dump of the time when it hangs? Usually shutdown is blocked for 20 seconds if there are still open transactions that have not been closed.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar issue just a couple hours ago, when I accidentally made a call to `db.shutdown()` on a `GraphDatabaseService` instance and tried calling other methods on the same instance afterwards. Maybe you can post some code so we obtain more information to reason about. By far the most probable cause of your issue is what I described.